# Prolog - get the first list from a list of lists

Tags: prolog

I've got a list consisting of smaller lists inside of it, each list consisting of 2 items:

```
[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]
```

I'm using a function called take(1,L,R) to take the first item from list L and return the item R. The code for the take function is here:

```
take(0,X,X).
take(N,[H|T],[H|R]):- 
    N>0, M is N-1,
    take(M,T,R).
```

At the moment a run may look like this:

```
1 ?- take(1,[[a],[b],[c]],Taken).
Taken = [[a], [b], [c]]
```

Which is the same as the input! This is the same for a "regular" 1-level-depth list:

```
2 ?- take(1,[a,b,c],Taken).
Taken = [a, b, c]
```

**Question:**
The question for you is how can I make the result look like:

```
1 ?- take(1,[[a],[b],[c]],Taken).
Taken = [a]
```

I want to return the first N items of the list I send it.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework...

Comment: It's better to use 0 as the index of the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base case `take(0, X, X).` is doing exactly what it says -- given any value X, the result is X. What I think you were trying to say is `take(1, [H|T], H).` (which yields the first element of a list).

What I think you're actually after is `take(0, _, [ ]).` which yields an empty list when "taking" 0 items from any list. This works well with your existing recursive case.

You say that you want to get the "first N items of the list" -- such a result must be stored in a list of N items. It follows that `take(1, [a, b, c], Taken)` would yield `Taken = [a]`, not `Taken = a`. Similarly, `take(1, [[a], [b], [c]], Taken).` would yield `Taken = [[a]].`. To special-case the take(1, ...) form to return the first item only (without it being wrapped in a list) would break your recursion.

Comment: the base case take(0, X, X). was meant to always return the input if N was 0, "you didnt want to remove anything, here you go" kind of thing. The whole function is supposed to work like "Take the N first items"

Comment: @shaungus: OK, I understand now the thinking behind your original base case, but it doesn't work with your recursion, which says "the take(n) of a list is the head of that list with the take(n-1) of the tail of that list" -- when n-1 reaches 0, the take should be 0 items. You could alternatively define the base case as `take(1, [H|T], H).`, leaving take(0) undefined, if this makes more sense to you (you'd need to change the N>0 subgoal to N>1 in your recursive case). I personally prefer having take(0) return an empty list since that makes sense and seems valid to me ("give me 0 items")

Comment: ok, well I might have had two different ways of thinking depending on where I was in the function, I can see it now X). Anyways I got it working, thanks